# Prove that a sequence is decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose that 0 < a < 1
Show that {a^n} is a decreasing sequence.

Yes, this is a homework question. I think I can solve it using induction, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Multiply the inequality throughout by $a$.

Comment: $a^n = a * a^{n-1} < 1*a^{n-1}$. Thus, it is a decreasing sequence.

Comment: Use the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to prove $a^{n+1} < a^n$ for all $n$. Start with $0 < a < 1$. Multiply the equation by $a^n$. Since $0 < a$, we have $0 < a^n$ as well. So we get $0 < a^{n+1} < a^n$.